# URL blocked off in API request, but displays properly when I go to the link in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, get, request

I'm making a simple app to make an API call and jsut display data, one piece of data is an image from a URL. It's weird because I get a 403 error in the deployed version of my app (on heroku), but my local version works fine. Also, if I jsut copy the url of the image and paste it into chrome, it loads the image fine. How can I work around this? I made it in angular.

```
  $scope.bigDisplayGet = (movie) ->

    $http(method: "GET", url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/", params: {t: movie.Title}

    ).success((data, status, headers, config) ->
      $scope.bigDisplay = data
      console.log "bigDisplay:", data
    ).error (data, status, headers, config) ->
      console.log "error mayneee"
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't us an `img` tag for this?

Comment: Also are you just not getting the img? does the rest of the data come back?